# Invalid Object name "myTempCategoryTable"

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

When I execute this stored procedure many of the lines are getting executed successfully but at some line its giving an error "`invalid object name myTempCategoryTable`". Please find a part of stored procedure where I am getting an error. The same stored procedure works for other database but for one database it doesn't. Is there any permission issue?
Please help.

Sql server stored proc:

```
set  @sql= 'CREATE TABLE myTempCategoryTable(MonthNo int,Months NVARCHAR(200),SESSION_ID NVARCHAR(200),' 

            SELECT @MIN_SNO= MIN(SNO) FROM #TempCategory  WHERE SESSIONID=@SESSIONID 
            SELECT @MAX_SNO= MAX(SNO) FROM #TempCategory  WHERE SESSIONID=@SESSIONID 

            WHILE(@MIN_SNO <= @MAX_SNO )
            BEGIN

                SELECT  @CUR_COLUMN= TextVal FROM  #TempCategory WHERE SESSIONID=@SESSIONID and SNO = @MIN_SNO

                IF(@MIN_SNO <= @MAX_SNO )
                BEGIN
                set  @sql = @sql +  REPLACE (REPLACE(@CUR_COLUMN,'-','_'),'\','') + ' NVARCHAR(200),'
                END
                ELSE
                BEGIN

                set  @sql = @sql +  REPLACE (REPLACE(@CUR_COLUMN,'-','_'),'\','') + ' NVARCHAR(200)'
                END

                SET @MIN_SNO = @MIN_SNO+1
            END

            SET @sql = @sql + ')'

            exec (@sql)

        END

      SElect  B.MonthNo,B.Months,A.SESSIONID,A.TextVal, B.TotalCost
      into #c from #TempCategory A inner JOIN  #Temp  B  ON   A.OCBProcessID=B.OCBProcessID
      order by  B.OCBProcessID

     DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
     DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SELECT @ColumnName= ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','')     + PlatformArea
    FROM (select distinct '"'+ case when  PM.OCBProcessDesc='Test Preparation' then 'Test_Preparation'  
    when PM.OCBProcessDesc='Test Excecution' then 'Test_Excecution' 
    when PM.OCBProcessDesc='Test Debug Activities' then 'Test_Debug_Activities' 
    when PM.OCBProcessDesc='Test Reporting' then 'Test_Reporting' end +'"' AS PlatformArea  from  OCBProcessDetails PM) AS Weeks

    print @ColumnName
        DECLARE @table TABLE ( id VARCHAR(50) )
        DECLARE @x INT = 0
        DECLARE @firstcomma INT = 0
        DECLARE @nextcomma INT = 0

        SET @x = LEN(@ColumnName) - LEN(REPLACE(@ColumnName, ',', '')) + 1 -- number of ids in id_list

        WHILE @x > 0
        BEGIN
            SET @nextcomma = CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(',', @ColumnName, @firstcomma + 1) = 0
                                    THEN LEN(@ColumnName) + 1
                                    ELSE CHARINDEX(',', @ColumnName, @firstcomma + 1)
                                END
            INSERT  INTO @table
            VALUES  ( SUBSTRING(@ColumnName, @firstcomma + 1, (@nextcomma - @firstcomma) - 1) )
            SET @firstcomma = CHARINDEX(',', @ColumnName, @firstcomma + 1)
            SET @x = @x - 1
        END

    SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 

    N'INSERT INTO myTempCategoryTable
    SELECT  *  FROM   #c 
    PIVOT
    (SUM(TotalCost)
    FOR TextVal IN ('+@ColumnName+')) AS P'

    print @DynamicPivotQuery
    EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

Comment: You are storing myTempCategoryTable definition in @ sql variable. Please print the value of this variable and check why this table is not created. There can be multiple possibilities like -  1) MIN(SNO)  or MAX(SNO)  FROM #TempCategory  is returning null    2)  TextVal FROM  #TempCategory is null and adding this value in sql variable will result into null and no table will be created.

Comment: @RahulRichhariya when i am trying to print @ sql its displaying blank. but values of min , mx, textval are not null